# Method works outside of Class, but not inside

Tags: ruby

The method "find" seems to work when I pull it out of the Class and test it, but for some reason it is returning empty when it is inside the Class. I can't figure out why...

```
class Dictionary

  def entries
    @entries ||= {}
  end

  def add(entry)

    if entry.is_a?(String) == true
      @entries = {entry => nil}
    else
      @entries= entry
    end
  end

  def keywords
    @entries.keys.sort
  end

  def include?(word)
    entries.keys.include?(word)
  end

  def find(word)
    result = {}
    entries.each_pair do |key, value|
      if key =~ /#{word}/
        result[key] = value
      end
    end

    result
  end
end
```

It gets stuck at this part of the spec...

```
it 'finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.add('fiend' => 'wicked person')
    @d.add('great' => 'remarkable')
    @d.find('fi').should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}
end
```

The error says...
    expected: {"fish" => "aquatic animal", "fiend" => "wicked person"} 
    got: {} (using ==) 
    Diff: @@ -1, 3, +1 @@
    -"fiend" => "wicked person"
    -"fish" => "aquatic animal"
    # ./11_dictionary/dictionary_spec.rb:67:in 'block (2 levels) in >'

Comment: Just put the example also, which you tried with this code and you found not working, It will help us to backtrack.

Comment: Okay thanks, I added the part of the spec that it gets stuck at.

Comment: Ok.. What error you got. when you ran this test ? Post the same in your question. These all needed to help you out.

Comment: Thank you, error is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add method replaces the entire entries hash, rather than actually adding an entry. Fix that, and the find method should work.

For completeness, here's how I would implement `add`:

```
def add(entry)
  if entry.is_a?(Hash)
    @entries.merge!(entry)
  else
    @entries[entry] = nil
  end
end
```